# How to Read ' n ' line from a text file and store it to another text file in python

Tags: python-3.x

I have a text file as **"file_in.txt"**.I want read the first three lines from that
file and Write the those three lines read from **"file_in.txt"** to a new file
called "file_out.txt".

After write it, read **"file_out.txt"** and Print it's contents

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
file_in = "file_in.txt"
file_out = "file_out.txt"
data = ""

# read the first 3 lines of file_in.txt
with open(file_in, 'r') as f:
    for i in range(3):
        data += f.readline()

# write to file_out.txt
with open(file_out, 'w') as f:
    f.write(data)

# read the content of file_out.txt
with open(file_out, 'r') as f:
    content = f.read()
    print(content)
```